# Cambiar la estructura de una tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

En este caso voy a utilizar **ALTER TABLE** para llevar el **AUTO_INCREMENT** a cero **(0)**.

El objetivo es llevar la tabla a 0 sin tener que eliminarla y crear una nueva.
Para hacerlo solo tenemos que escribir la siguiente orden:

```
ALTER TABLE 'nombre_de_la_tabla' AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALTER TABLE** puede cambiar la estructura de una tabla, como agrega o elimina columnas, crea o elimina índices, modificar el tipo de columnas existentes o renombrar columnas o la propia tabla. También puede cambiar características como el motor de almacenamiento utilizado para la tabla o el comentario de la tabla.

Fuente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html